# join on its own in Jet

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, self-join

I am joining a query with it self and my code is working ok on ase isql. However when I want to use it in access 2007 I get the following error "The derived table expression is missing a correlation name. Check derived table syntax in the reference manual"
The original code does something like this:

```
 select TT.name, TT.lastname, max(amount) as maxsalecurrentweek
 from sales
 inner join
 (select s1.id_employee, e.name, e.lastname, e.address, e.age, e.id_employee 
 from employee e
 join sales s1 on e.id_emplyoee = s1.id_employee
 where 
 some conditions here) as TT
 on sales.id_employee = TT.id_employee
 group by
 TT.name, TT.lastname
```

In the original code I join more tables in the inner query as well as some where conditions. But the above code should illustrate what I do.

It looks like the way I join the table with it self is the problem in access. Does anyone know what How is the correct sysntaxis? Or if access/JET/ACE support this inner join with it self approach?

Here is the original code:

```
select max(tort140.BEL_GRLAG_AP) as MaxPensjonGr, TT.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR,
TT.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM, TT.AvtaleID, TT.Orgnr, TT.Arbeidsgiver, 
TT.Sivilstatus, TT.Polisestatus, TT.Årslønn from tort140 

    inner join 

        (select distinct tort128.NUM_AVTALE_ID as AvtaleID,
         tort009.IDE_ARBGIV_NR as Orgnr,
         tort134.NVN_ARBGIV as Arbeidsgiver,
         tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM as DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM,
         tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR as IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR,
         tort001.STA_SIVILSTATUS as Sivilstatus,
         tort128.typ_status as Polisestatus, 
         tort128.rte_polisegrad as Polisegrad,
         tort140.BEL_LOENN_AAR as Årslønn,
         tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138"
         from tort140 left join (tort138 join (tort128 join (tort134 join (tort009 join (tort001 join tort127 
         on tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM=tort001.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM and tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR=tort001.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR)
         on tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM=tort009.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM and tort127.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR=tort009.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR)
         on tort009.IDE_ARBGIV_NR=tort134.IDE_ARBGIV_NR)
         on tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT127 = tort127.IDE_SEKV_TORT127)
         on tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT128 = tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT128)
         on tort140.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 = tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138)

         where tort128.NUM_AVTALE_ID = '102356' and tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_FOM <= 20120101
            and (tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_TOM >= 19520000 or tort128.DAT_GYLDIG_TOM is null
            and tort128.DAT_HISTORISK is null and tort128.TYP_STATUS= 'akt' and tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM >= 19650000
            and tort127.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM <= 19550000 and tort127.DAT_TERMINERT is null and tort127.DAT_REGISTRERT<= 19550000
            and tort009.DAT_SLUTT is null and tort134.DAT_HISTORISK is null
            and tort138.DAT_AKSJON=(select max(p.DAT_AKSJON) from tort138 p where 1=1 and p.IDE_SEKV_TORT128=tort128.IDE_SEKV_TORT128)

          ) as TT

          on TT.IDE_SEKV_TORT138 = tort140.IDE_SEKV_TORT138

Group by TT.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR, TT.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM, TT.AvtaleID, TT.Orgnr,
TT.Arbeidsgiver, TT.Sivilstatus, TT.Polisestatus, TT.Årslønn from tort140
```

The inner query works on access 2007 without any problem. I got the error message when I write the inner join. 
Do you think this query can be suited into access?? Am I missing some brakets or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a join type in MS Access, Join on its own will not work.

```
from employee e
 INNER join sales s1 on e.id_emplyoee = s1.id_employee
```

Edit per comments, the line above is taken from the posted SQL and fits back in like so:

```
select TT.name, TT.lastname, max(amount) as maxsalecurrentweek
 from sales
 inner join
 (select s1.id_employee, e.name, e.lastname, e.address, e.age, e.id_employee 
 from employee e
 INNER join sales s1 on e.id_emplyoee = s1.id_employee
 where 
 some conditions here) as TT
 on sales.id_employee = TT.id_employee
 group by
 TT.name, TT.lastname
```

Comment: And note that this is not a self-join.  Also, note the error message refers to "the derived table", which should help find similar errors in the future.

Comment: I dont quite understand how I am gonna take max(amount) and the other columns from the inner query. Can you be a bit more specific? Thanks!! (My sql programming level is rather basic)

Comment: If you are working in MS Access, you can paste the sql with the change I have suggested into SQL view of the query design window and the fields (columns) will all be shown. You can add and remove them from the design grid by drag and drop.

Comment: Any fields you add either have to be GROUP BY or some calculation.

Comment: the code I wrote was just to point out the main issue I encountered in access. My original code is more complex, and it connects to a sybase database using a ADODB.Recordeset, so I cannot just drag and drop. The problem with my original code is that the only way that I found to get what I need is joining the inner query with it self. I dont see how just writing what you suggested will give me what I need coz I join 9 tables in the inner query. Where exactly should i paste your suggestion? instead of what?

Comment: This is a disadvantage of posting imaginary sql. The sql in your example would run with a single change. If you wish to post more detail to your question that illustrates what you have and what you want, another answer may be possible. The line above is taken from your sql. The only addition I made was INNER which is the only change you need to make the code run in MS Access.

Comment: I just posted the original code. I would really appreciate if you can take a quick look and see if the "inner join" will make it work. Thanks Remou.

Comment: No, it won't. The syntax is not even remotely like MS Access, it is far too complicated to just work out here.

Comment: I managed to run my code on access! JET undestand the above syntax with no problems. The problem in the above code is the ')' after tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138!

Comment: I find that very strange indeed. The very end shows `from tort140` : `Group by TT.IDE_KUNDE_PRSNR, TT.DAT_KUNDE_FOEDT_NUM, TT.AvtaleID, TT.Orgnr,
TT.Arbeidsgiver, TT.Sivilstatus, TT.Polisestatus, TT.Årslønn from tort140 `

Comment: ... and you have a quote here `tort138.IDE_SEKV_TORT138"`